# weblogic classloading binary resource

Tags: java, resources, weblogic, classloader, weblogic-10.x

I'm trying to use a binary resource in my application. I need it for crypt/decript passwords. The file is located in the "classes" folder of my ear, just like properties files that the application access without problems.

Anyway, I am loading the files as follows.

```
ClassLoader.class.getResourceAsStrem(/file.xxxx);
```

But in the case of the binary file the resultant InputStream is null.

The question is, why it works with properties files and does not with a binary file? What can i do for load a binary resource?

Best regards.

Answer (score 0):

1. Ensure that the file is available on the class path.
2. Use the context class loader instead - this will ensure that the code trying to look up the file can reside in a shared library as well.

Something on the lines of:

```
Thread.currentThread().getContextClassLoader().getResourceAsStream(..)
```

Hope that helps.

Comment: Looks a good idea. I'll try tomorrow in the office. But, why works with the properties files and does not with a binary file?

Comment: I'm make use of the next code for loading the resource:

InputStream is = Thread.currentThread().getContextClassLoader().getResourceAsStream(/myBinaryFile.bin)

The problem now is that weblogic is not returning an InputStrem, is returning a propetary object named "SafeZipFileInputStream"

Comment: If you do a javap on the SafeZipFileInputStream, you will notice that this class extends from java.io.FilterInputStream which in turn extends from java.io.InputStream

So, as long as you are working with the base classes, it shouldn't make a difference what the stream type is.

Is there any problem if you use it as just an InputStream?

Comment: Yes, the resultant file is the weblogic generated jar ($WL_HOME/servers..../6iiuve/war/WEB-INF/lib/_wl_cls_gen.jar) from war file, isn't my binary file.

Comment: Why not try to print out all the available resources first to see if your file is being picked up or not? Same code as above, just that instead of *getResourceAsStream()*, you do a *getResources()* and then iterate over the enumeration and print them out to see if your file is even showing up or not.

Comment: I had the exact same problem getting a SafeZipFileInputStream from WLS trying to load an image from the jar of the deployed application. 

In my case loading the image failed since I used InputStream directly to read bytes instead of using BufferedInputStream (feeding the InputStream). 

This was no problem while unit-testing the same code on my local machine at all. I guess the unzip stream reader needs the BufferedInputStream to function properly. 

Hope this helps someone else.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of ClassLoader use the class name where you are currently in.

```
YourClass.class.getResourceAsStrem(/file.xxxx);
```